# How do i query a database with local timezone ? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-6

I am in the Asia/Taipei timezone(utc+8).

Rails database time are stored in UTC format, so when I wanna query records that created_at time at 5:xx.

```
Model.where('EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at) = ?', 5)
```

It always got 13:xx records(5+8), how to fix query with timezone?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed query with timezone

```
Model.where("EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CONVERT_TZ(created_at,'+00:00','+08:00')) = ?", 5)
```